# Hibernate Foreign Key Constraint issue for many to one

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

First, let me say that I know this is yet "another" Hibernate issue with foreign keys. However, none of the solutions I found on here seem to work for me. So here I am, looking for help.

**Database**

This is the parent table

```
CREATE TABLE FORM (
    FORM_ID    NUMBER,
    NAME       VARCHAR2(40),
CONSTRAINT form_pk PRIMARY KEY (form_id));
```

And this is the child table

```
CREATE TABLE REJECTION (
    REJECTION_ID    NUMBER,
    REASON    VARCHAR2(2000),
    FORM_ID    NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT rej_pk PRIMARY_KEY (rejection_id),
CONSTRAINT rej_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCE form(form_id));
```

Each of these table have a trigger that populates the primary key before insertion

**Entity Objects**

This is the Entity Object for the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FORM")
public class Form implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FORM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "FORM_SEQ")
    // This uses a trigger to generate the ID
    private Integer formId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "form")
    private Set<Rejection> rejections;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And here is the Entity Object for the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REJECTION")
public class Rejection implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REJECTION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G2")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G2", sequenceName = "REJECTION_SEQ")
    // This uses a trigger to generate the ID
    private Integer rejectionId;

    @Column(name="REASON")
    private String reason;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FORM_ID")
    private Form form;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@someConnection</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">pancakes</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">syrup</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 from DUAL</property>

        <mapping class="com.entity.Form"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.entity.Rejection"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**The Code**

And finally, here is the code snippet I am using:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Form form = new Form();
form.setName("Test");

session.save(form);

System.out.println("Form ID: " + form.getFormId());

Rejections rej = new Rejection();
rej.setReason("Some Reason");
rej.setForm(form);

session.save(rej);

System.out.println("Rejection ID: " + rej.getRejectionId());

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

**The Error**

The error I am getting is: 
`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER.REJ_FK1) violated - parent key not found`

Both of the System.outs actually return a value.

What I am thinking is that there is an issue with the trigger generating the IDs.

I appreciate ANY help or direction on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The issue was with the triggers and the SequenceGenerators on the IDS. It was essentially generating 2 IDS... one from the trigger and one from Hibernate. Hibernate was trying to use  the one from the Trigger when it was needing the one from Hibernate.

I just disabled the triggers and it worked fine :-)